How to apply event listeners to new elements
i want to make an Jupyter notebook-like input, where i have spans as inputs, and when the user clicks Enter a new input is added to the page and so on. the problem is the listener for click event works only on the first input. how can i make it functional on all the blocks.

    $inputSpan.on('click', function() {
        $inputSpan.attr('contenteditable', 'true').focus();
    });

    $inputSpan.on('blur', function() {
        $inputSpan.removeAttr('contenteditable');
    });

    $inputSpan.on('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            if (event.shiftKey) {
                // ... action for enter click
            } else {
                // ... end editing 
                $inputSpan.blur();
                event.preventDefault();
                add_block(); // this function append a new block to the page
            }
        }
    });

above is the code i used.

What does your html look like, including the new input that's added? What is $inputSpan? I think it's as simple as replacing $inputSpan with the new input.

I've created a runnable snippet that demonstrates the behavior you desire. Note that I have used INPUTs instead of SPANs, but this doesn't effect how to do it / how to make it work


function add_block(e) {
  console.log("add_block: " + e.target);
  let toAdd = e.target.closest("P").cloneNode(true);
  console.log("to add: " + toAdd);
  addListeners($(toAdd.querySelector("INPUT")));
  $(e.target).after(toAdd);
}

function addListeners($inputSpan) {

$inputSpan.on('click', function() {
        $inputSpan.attr('contenteditable', 'true').focus();
        console.log("click");
    });

    $inputSpan.on('blur', function() {
        $inputSpan.removeAttr('contenteditable');
        console.log("blur");
    });

    $inputSpan.on('keydown', function(event) {
      console.log("keydown");
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            if (event.shiftKey) {
                // ... action for enter click
            } else {
                // ... end editing 
                $inputSpan.blur();
                event.preventDefault();
                add_block(event); // this function append a new block to the page
            }
        }
    });
    console.log("foo");
}

addListeners($("INPUT"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<P>Enter Info:<Input name="foo" /></P>



